# como executar um comando do powershell dentro de uma janela iniciada por um script

Tags: powershell

Tenho um arquivo script.ps1 e a primeira linha dele consiste em abrir uma outra janela do powershell:

```
powershell Start-Process powershell -Verb runAs
```

Porém o problema é que preciso executar outros comandos dentro da janela criada.

Por exemplo:

```
powershell Start-Process powershell -Verb runAs
echo ola
```

Quero que o echo ola execute na janela que eu criei na primeira linha e não na janela padrão que utilizei para executar o script

Answer (score 0):

Algo nesse sentido?

```
powershell Start-Process powershell -Verb runAs  {echo hello; Read-Host}
```

Comment: Se tiver uma nova pergunta, faça-a clicando no botão [Fazer pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Inclua um link para esta pergunta se ajudar a fornecer contexto. - [Da Revisão](/review/low-quality-posts/306076)

Comment: Não entendi o pq do seu comentário @KayoBruno

Comment: Também não entendi....